# How I can draw a line in a UICollectionView?

Tags: ios, swift

I want to let the user select multiple cells with a single gesture, and if the selected cells compose a correct word, it will be represented by a permanent drawn line, otherwise the line will disapear.

Check this image example:

[image]

and video: https://youtu.be/wzuCo6q8xDY

My first approach was to use a UIPanGestureRecognizer... but it is only returning the last selected cell..

How I can draw a line inside a CollectionView and get determine which cells are behind the drawn line?

I've thought about this problem all day and wondered if somebody has an approach to solve this.

I'm grateful for every tiny bit of help, thank you :)

Comment: Up voted because I *do not* believe that is *just* a UICollectionView. At the very least, I think there's a clear background UIView of sort in front of it detecting touches. Probably much more logic also, but  (1) that isn't a "line", and (2) how do you make an alpha-diminished touch pan *not* change the backgroundColor of every cell - in other words, a CGRect - look like that.

Comment: Why are you using a collection view for this? How would you distinguish between scrolling and selecting?

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way to accomplish that would be using UIPanGestureRecognizer to your Collection View.

```
collectionView.gestureRecognizer(UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(handlePan(gesture:))))
```

The handlePan(gesture:) method would be like this:

```
func handlePan(gesture: UIPanGestureRecognizer){
    let indexPath = collectionView.indexPathForItem(at: gesture.location(in: collectionView))

    if let index = indexPath {

        collectionView.selectItem(at: index, animated: true, scrollPosition: UICollectionViewScrollPosition())

    }

}
```

Don't forget to allow multiple selection in your collectionView:

`collectionView.allowsMultipleSelection = true`

You can also override the isSelect property in your UICollectionViewCell:

```
class CustomCell: UICollectionViewCell {

    override var isSelected: Bool {
        didSet {
            if isSelected {
                backgroundColor = .green
            } else {
                backgroundColor = .blue
            }
        }
    }

}
```

In this case I'm only modifying the background, but you can modify to whatever you need.